# How to properly populate page headers in Nuxt generated dynamic pages using Apollo?

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo, nuxt.js

I have a Nuxt.js, statically generated site that has some dynamic pages. I'm using a GraphQL based headless CMS (DatoCMS) to provide the data for these pages, accessed using Apollo (@nuxt/apollo). I have it generating all the routes correctly but when I navigate to these pages from my site nav I'm receiving the following error 3 times:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '_seoMetaTags' of undefined
at f.head (cf150f1920d36ab67139.js:1)
at wn.get (008dfc959ff6e6a713a0.js:2)
at wn.evaluate (008dfc959ff6e6a713a0.js:2)
at f.$metaInfo (008dfc959ff6e6a713a0.js:2)
at f.created (008dfc959ff6e6a713a0.js:2)
at Qt (008dfc959ff6e6a713a0.js:2)
at fn (008dfc959ff6e6a713a0.js:2)
at f.t._init (008dfc959ff6e6a713a0.js:2)
at new f (008dfc959ff6e6a713a0.js:2)
at 008dfc959ff6e6a713a0.js:2
```

This is coming from the head code in my page component so clearly something isn't being generated correctly. I can also see in the Chrome network tab that calls are being made to the GraphQL interface which also tells me the static generation isn't working correctly.

Here's the head() and apollo portions of my page component:

```
head() {
    return {
        title: this.blogPost._seoMetaTags.find(element => {
            return element.tag === 'title';
        }).content,
        meta: [
            { hid: 'keywords', keywords: this.blogPost.keywords },
            { hid: 'description', description: this.blogPost._seoMetaTags.find(element => {
                return element.tag === 'meta' && element.attributes.name === 'description';
            }).attributes.content}
        ],
        script: [
            { src: 'https://cdn.commento.io/js/commento.js', defer: true }
        ]
    }
},
apollo: {
    blogPost: {
        query: gpl`
            query BlogPost($slug: String!) {
                blogPost(filter: { slug:{ eq: $slug }}) {
                    title
                    titleColor {
                        hex
                    }
                    slug
                    author
                    keywords
                    _seoMetaTags {
                        tag
                        attributes
                        content
                    }
                    _firstPublishedAt
                    banner {
                      id
                      url
                      title
                    }
                    content {
                        ... on HeadingRecord {
                            _modelApiKey
                            heading
                        }
                        ... on SubHeadingRecord {
                            _modelApiKey
                            subHeading
                        }
                        ... on TextRecord {
                            _modelApiKey
                            content
                        }
                        ... on CodeRecord {
                            _modelApiKey
                            codeBlock
                        }
                        ... on ImageRecord {
                            _modelApiKey
                            image {
                                id
                                height
                                width
                                url
                                title
                                alt
                            }
                        }
                        ... on VideoRecord {
                            _modelApiKey
                            video {
                                height
                                provider
                                providerUid
                                thumbnailUrl
                                title
                                url
                                width
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        `,
        prefetch({ route }) {
            return {
                slug: route.params.slug
            };
        },
        variables() {
            return {
                slug: this.$route.params.slug
            };
        }
```

And my nuxt.config.js if it helps:

```
const pkg = require('./package')
```

const webpack = require('webpack');
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
import { execute, makePromise } from 'apollo-link';
import { createHttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

module.exports = {
    mode: 'universal',

```
/*
** Headers of the page
*/
head: {
    title: pkg.name,
    htmlAttrs: {
        lang: 'en'
    },
    meta: [
        { charset: 'utf-8' },
        { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
        { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: pkg.description }
    ],
    link: [
        { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' },
        { rel: 'stylesheet', href: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/tonsky/FiraCode@1.206/distr/fira_code.css' }
    ]
},

/*
** Customize the progress-bar color
*/
loading: { color: '#fff' },

/*
** Global CSS
*/
css: [
],

/*
** Plugins to load before mounting the App
*/
plugins: [
],

/*
** Nuxt.js modules
*/
modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/style-resources',
    '@nuxtjs/apollo',
    '@nuxtjs/google-analytics'
],

/*
** @nuxtjs/google-analytics settings
*/
googleAnalytics: {
    id: 'UA-136517294-1'
},

/*
** @nuxtjs/style-resources settings
*/
styleResources: {
    scss: [
        './assets/css/*.scss'
    ]
},

/*
** Apollo setup for DatoCMS graphql queries
*/
apollo: {
    includeNodeModules: true,
    clientConfigs: {
        default: '@/apollo/default.js'
    }
},

/*
** Build configuration
*/
build: {
    postcss: {
        preset: {
            features: {
                customProperties: false
            }
        }
    },
    /*
    ** You can extend webpack config here
    */
    extend(config, ctx) {
    }
},

/*
** Generate configuration
*/
generate: {
    routes: function(callback) {
        // Get the list of posts
        const uri = 'https://graphql.datocms.com';
        const link = new createHttpLink({ uri: uri, fetch: fetch });
        const operation = {
            query: gql`
            {
                allBlogPosts {
                    id
                    slug
                    keywords
                    _seoMetaTags {
                        tag
                        attributes
                        content
                    }
                }
            }`,
            context: {
                headers: {
                    authorization: 'Bearer <my token>'
                }
            }
        };

        makePromise(execute(link, operation))
            .then(data => {
                // Build the routes from the posts
                const postRoutes = data.data.allBlogPosts.map(item => {
                    return { route: `/blog/${item.slug}`, payload: { keywords: item.keywords, seoData: item._seoMetaTags }};
                });

                // Register the routes
                callback(null, postRoutes);
            })
            .catch(error => console.log(`received error ${error}`));
    }
}
```

}

Comment: requests still will be made. See https://github.com/nuxt/rfcs/issues/22

Comment: @Aldarund Yes! That's exactly what I'm running into. The static pages seem to be generating okay but the head code is retriggering the data queries or something. Unfortunately it doesn't look like there's much of a solution. Might be time to play with Gridsome instead of Nuxt. If you create an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expect all api requests to be bundled into app and not made anymore, thats not how nuxt currently work. It still will do requests to the api`s on client navigation withing app.

There is a plan for making full static mode in nuxt, you can track it here https://github.com/nuxt/rfcs/issues/22